# How to traverse through JSON data dynamically and make changes ..?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, parsing, object

I have a map like data in JSON

```
var map =  {        
    level1 : {          
            x : {name:'level1 x' , },
            y : {name:'level1 y'}
    },
    level2 : {          
            x : {name:'level2 x'},
            y : {name:'level2 y'}
    }
```

}

I need to traverse through this data , i am getting the traverse path as an string

```
"level1 x name" , "level2 y name";
```

How can i parse through the JSON data from that string path..??

What i tried is ,

```
var path = "level1 x name".split(" ");
var pointer = map; // assuming it will take reference of map and change will cause to map also
 for (var i = 0, len = path.length; i < len; i++) {
   if(pointer){
      pointer = pointer[path[i]];
   }else{
     pointer = map[path[i]];
   } 
 }
 pointer = "level1 xx";

console.log(map);
```

But map data is not changing.. how to loop through with reference and change the value ..?

Comment: its just an js object literal ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you get your value:

```
var name = [map].concat("level1 x name".split(" ")).reduce(function(prev, curr) {
    return prev[curr];
});

console.log(name);

// -> 'level1 x'
```

JavaScript passes arguments by value, not by reference.

For your convenience I changed your code for you to acceomplish what you asked for:

```
var path = "level1 x name".split(" ");
var pointer = map; // assuming it will take reference of map and change will cause to map also
 for (var i = 0, len = path.length-1; i < len; i++) {
   if(pointer){
      pointer = pointer[path[i]];
   }else{
     pointer = map[path[i]];
   } 
 }
 pointer[path[path.length-1]] = "level1 xx";

console.log(map);
```

Comment: ys.. im able to read tht value with the code i have posted.. i need to get the reference like map['level1']['x']['name']

Comment: its passing bt refrence only rt..?

Comment: @SarathSaleem: There are no references in JavaScript. `pointer` is the second last level in the hierachy of the object `map`.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22890/discussion-between-sarath-saleem-and-amberlamps)

Answer (score -2):

Try This.. Change the path variable as required. It is working fine. I just verified it in firebug.

```
var map =  {        
    level1 : {          
            x : {name:'level1 x' , },
            y : {name:'level1 y'}
    },
    level2 : {          
            x : {name:'level2 x'},
            y : {name:'level2 y'}
    }
};
var path = "level1 x name";
var pathInfor = path.split(' ');
var pathLength = pathInfor.length;
//alert(map[pathInfor[0]][pathInfor[1]][pathInfor[2]].name);

for(level in map)
{
    if(level == pathInfor[0]){
       var selLevel = map[level];
        for(xy in selLevel)
        {
           if(xy == pathInfor[1])
           {
                  var selVariable = map[level][xy];
                    for(innerVal in selVariable){
                               if(innerVal == pathInfor[2]){
                               alert(map[level][xy][innerVal]);
                               }
                    }
           }
        }
    }
}
```

In this method you are not required to check with the values. If you want to print all the values form JSON, remove the condition.

Comment: ofcourse.. its the hardcoded version.. may string and map data will change..i need a generic one.

Comment: what about the nested levels? Will it vary?